# Why did I get question banned today?

Tags: support, post-ban

I've been a user for like 3 months. I have 3 questions that have a score of -1 and I have at least 2 questions that have a score of +2 or higher.

What went wrong? And before you think it's a "noob" reason, I've been using Stack for 4 months and I have never been question banned before on any Stack sites.

**Also, why couldn't I get a suspension instead? I'm not new so yeah!**

Comment: The negative scores might do it. How many answers have you posted? How many deleted questions?

Comment: I dunno about deleted but I never answered any questions since I'm usually on Stack (1.6k rep)

Comment: "Stack" is not a sufficient description for a site in the StackExchange network.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Although a quick look at [the OP's network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/3311833/puretppc?tab=accounts) says the two highest-rep accounts are Stack Overflow (1659 rep) and MSO (268 rep).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: That task is not that easily performed in the SE app and my point remains still ;)

Comment: @gparyani Are you sure?

Comment: I've edited [one of your questions](http://superuser.com/questions/708315/aero-peek-not-working-when-hovering-over-taskbar-icon) and upvoted it. Surely this did not deserve to be downvoted this far...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of the 10 questions you've asked:

- 2 were deleted (both were downvoted)
- 3 (different ones) were closed
- Only 2 have more than a single upvote, and one of those is closed

Moderators are not privy to the exact algorithm behind the question ban, so I don't know for sure, but you're *probably* right on the edge. In case you weren't aware, deleted questions still affect the q-ban algorithm.

I would suggest taking some time to edit your existing questions to improve them. Read "[How To Ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask)" in detail, and update your existing questions to fit those criteria. Undeleting some of the self-deleted questions may also help.

Making some contributions back to the community also affects the question ban algorithm. Consider answering some questions as well, as this can help boost your score if you provide high-quality answers.

Comment: Only 1 upvote? There's 3 actually that have upvotes, ok maybe 2 since 1 is closed. Hmm, I thought only downvoted ones contribute towards this. Uh for the deleted ones, I don't really know if I can even fix that because the quality is way too bad I gotta say :(

Comment: @Ramhound Explain how I fix questions that aren't allowed on this site? No grammar is needed to be fixed. The reason is that they're off topic so how do I make them on topic? As for my closed questions, I don't know how to make them. Wow I'm innocent why ban me? I know how this place works I'm not a noob

Comment: @Ramhound Why don't you try to help me out on this maybe? I'm not good at trying to fix questions. Why don't you maybe suggest edits for me? I feel that it's not a fair ban really

Comment: @puretppc if you really feel the ban is unfair, you can use the "contact us" link to contact the Stack Exchange team and request a review. However, the best course of action is to carefully read [ask] and to edit your own previous questions, as I mentioned before.

Comment: You think I'm a noob at this? I've repeated this like 5 times that I'm not a noob and I know how this site works! Anyways sorry for temper but I'll try this ok. Or should I flag my best question for mod attention so I can explain myself about this ban?

Comment: @puretppc I'm just trying to help, so please be nice. Flagging for mod attention will do nothing, because we moderators are already aware of the situation via this meta post. As I previously stated, moderators do not know the exact details of the question ban algorithm and we do not have the ability to manually disable it. Your only choices are to improve your existing questions or contact the Stack Exchange team.

Comment: @nhinkle Why don't you help me fix them? I don't even know what to fix to be honest. That's the great problem is that if I think it's good but you don't think it's good. Why don't you at least list out what I need to be "fixed"?

Comment: @puretppc as I've said before, I do not know exactly what changes would push you back over the brink. I'm sorry, but I literally cannot list out what you need to fix. I do not have that information. You can read this info in [the help center](http://superuser.com/help/question-bans) on tips for reversing the question ban.

Comment: @puretppc We don't want people to game the system. Disclosing the ban algorithm, even to full ♦moderators, could lead to a long-term decline in overall content quality across the Stack Exchange network as people are likely to abuse the algorithm. See also this Coding Horror blog post: [Designing for Evil](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/designing-for-evil.html)

Comment: @puretppc Just to underscore what nhinkle wrote: Answer some questions with good answers that get upvotes.  Someone who only asks questions and never answers is taking without giving back.  You are question banned, but not answer banned.  It is time to give something back.