# What's the policy on a student systematically asking questions

Tags: support

The user [billnyeguy](https://superuser.com/users/714226/billnyeguy)
has today posted four questions taken from the
COMP Tia networking exam.

I have no idea if using our site to ask for explanation of study material
is allowed or not.

Personally, I don't see anything wrong with helping a student with a
difficult problem and have done so many times,
but I can't help the feeling that this guy is overdoing it.

What is the policy here ?
Are non-moderators supposed to do something in such a case ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I ask questions related to my assignments here?](//meta.superuser.com/q/11866)

Comment: @DavidPostill: Thanks, this means that the guy is doing something wrong. But is there something to be done about it? I already warned the guy about it on his second post, before posting here, but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Well downvoting his questions is one answer (he is currently question blocked as a result)

Comment: Just do the usual, vote to close, comment with a link to the relevant meta.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Curiosity: Are the rules for downvotes and their relation to question block published? What is this link?

Comment: @harrymc https://superuser.com/help/question-bans

Comment: @Mokubai: Thanks, I've already found it but there is no explanation on how the ban is triggered. My curiosity might be leading in directions you may prefer to leave obscure; my apologies in this case.

Comment: @harrymc https://meta.superuser.com/a/7662/19943 pretty much sums it up. Moderators don't have exact details of what causes a ban except to know that many low quality (downvoted) submissions is likely to cause it.

Comment: @Mokubai: Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have closed these questions because they fall out of the site scope which states:

> If you have a question about …
>
> - personal and home computer networking

The questions asked are about professional qualifications and networking in a professional environment and are not about "personal and home computer" networks.

As mentioned in the comments downvote and closures count towards a low quality ban and may result in users being blocked from asking future questions.

If you feel that questions are not on topic or are poor quality then you can vote to close and/or downvote as appropriate.